# This class must have only these 3 attributes

Tags: python

I must write a class Person with 3 attributes (Name,Surname,Age) in all his instances.
How can i set it that it cant be possible to add more attributes?

```
class Person:
   def __init__(self,name,surname,age):
        self.name=name
        self.surname=surname
        self.age=age
```

Comment: Does your assignment actually require you to block attempts to set other attributes, or is your assignment just telling you not to set any other attributes?

Answer (score 1):

use `__slots__`:

```py
class Person:
   __slots__ = ("name", "surname", "age")
   def __init__(self,name,surname,age):
        self.name=name
        self.surname=surname
        self.age=age
```

Read more here: [Usage of __slots__?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/472000/usage-of-slots)